# jQuery+WebMethod+UrlRewriting: how to distinguish parameter from server method name

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webmethod

My ASP.NET web site converts URLs like http://smth.com/player/1234 into request to "player" page with parameter id=1234

On the page I need to make a web-request to the 'GetData' method on this page. I would like to do the request using jQuery. All tutorials I've found (http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/, for instance) suggests to pass URL/method name in 'url' parameter of '$.ajax'

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "PageName.aspx/MethodName", // in my case that will be ... what?
  data: "{}",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(msg) {
    // Do something interesting here.
  }
});
```

The problem is that if I specify "player/1234/GetData" then request will be done to "player" page, but ASP.NET won't call GetData method...

Should I implement custom logic on this page and call 'GetData' in order to execute web-request? If yes, how can I identify that request is done to the WebMethod?

Or I should provide 'plain' url in the way like http://smth.com/player.aspx?Id=1234/GetData

I probably miss something? May be jquery does allow specify 'method name' in a separate field? Or I should configure my web site to handle that properly?

Please advise. Any ideas are welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dunno how to resolve the problem.. so instead I'm making request to web service (URL contains .asmx that bypass URL rewriting)...

If you know how to resolve the original problem - please advise!

Answer (score 1):

Budda, I saw your question while having the same problem.

My solution, probably not the best, was to add a fake extension to my calls, in my case "jq", like this:

```
url: "<%: ResolveUrl("~/PagePath/PageName.aspx") %>/WebMethod.jq"
```

Because I have one rule to remove the extension and another one to add a slash at the end of the URL I need to use
`<%: ResolveUrl("~/PagePath/PageName.aspx") %>`.
This is because when I enter the page my URL is `http://hostname/PagePath/PageName/` and if I call  the WebMethod through ajax the url would end up like `http://hostname/PagePath/PageName/PageName.aspx/WebMethod.jq`.

After you've added this fake extension you'll have to add a new rewrite rule to remove it prior the final execution:

```
<rule name="Clean Page WebMethods">
   <match url="(.*)\.jq$" />
   <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

If you have any other rules, you'll have to skip them with a condition, e.g. if you use one to remove extensions, you might need to add in the conditions of the rule something like this:

```
<add input="{R:2}" negate="true" pattern="\.jq" />
```

I'm using `{R:2}` because I found that the URL Rewrite Module doesn't take the `WebMethod.jq` as part of the url if it founds a `aspx` extension. The `{R:2}` would be for my pattern, but it may change for the pattern of your rules.

It may sound over complicated for just using a Page WebMethod, but after the initial configuration, you'll just have to add the `.jq` extension for your calls in your scripts.

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Well, this doesn't solve your problem, but I'll leave the answer there if someone hits the post having the same problem.